# Genexus GAM Messages

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

Does anyone know how I can change GAM messages? I'm getting strange characters.

Example:

```
Encoded:El+usuario+o+la+contrase%c3%b1a+no+es+correcta
```

Answer (score 1):

Hugo,

You may be running GeneXus v15 Upgrade 6 or lower. 
This issue has been fixed in v15 Upgrade 7.